# copy properties c# but check if a property is already set

Tags: c#

I working hard on a JSON-Deserializer on my own. Just for training. I am nearly finished, but I have a copying issue.

I already have this:

```
public void CopyValues<T>(T target, T source)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);

    var properties = t.GetProperties().Where(prop => prop.CanRead && prop.CanWrite);

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(source, null);
        if (value != null)
            prop.SetValue(target, value, null);
    }
}
```

The Main Problem is here. I have a Property containing 2 Properties. Like content.link and content.value.

If I use the Copy Function it copys right. No discussion. But if I put the copy function into a loop, and the data is filled up, the source having also
"content", but without link and value.

If I copy again, the already correctly filled properties are getting overridden, and the result is that I have only null at conent.link and content.value.

Is there a way, to check if link and value is set to null ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to copy the nested properties, you will need use a recursive function:

```
public static void DeepCopy<T>(T target, T source)
{
    DeepCloneImpl(typeof(T), source, target);
}
public static T DeepClone<T>(T template)
    where T : new()
{
    return (T)DeepCloneImpl(typeof(T), template);
}

private static object DeepCloneImpl(Type type, object template, object stump = null)
{
    if (template == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var clone = stump ?? Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    var clonableProperties = type.GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.GetMethod != null && x.SetMethod != null);
    foreach (var property in clonableProperties)
    {
        var propertyType = property.PropertyType;
        if (propertyType.GetTypeInfo().IsValueType || propertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(template);
            property.SetValue(clone, value);
        }
        else if (propertyType.GetTypeInfo().IsClass && propertyType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null)
        {
            var value = DeepCloneImpl(propertyType, property.GetValue(template));
            property.SetValue(clone, value);
        }
        else if (propertyType.IsArray)
        {
            var source = property.GetValue(template) as Array;
            if (source == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var elementType = propertyType.GetElementType();
            if (elementType.GetTypeInfo().IsValueType || elementType == typeof(string))
            {
                var copies = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, source.Length);
                Array.Copy(source, copies, source.Length);
                property.SetValue(clone, copies);
            }
            else if (elementType.GetTypeInfo().IsClass)
            {
                var copies = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, source.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
                {
                    var copy = DeepCloneImpl(elementType, source.GetValue(i));
                    copies.SetValue(copy, i);
                }
                property.SetValue(clone, copies);
            }
        }
    }

    return clone;
}
```

This should cover most of the use case, however you will have to handle self/circular references.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, the problem is values are being overridden. And from looking at your method, it appears to be doing what you'd expect, it's a soft clone of property values. Depending on what a correctly filled property is in your situation, you'll have to make a comparison that prevents the property from being set again. Perhaps `value != null` should actually be `value == null` so that you're only setting the value when there wasn't already one. Because of the generic typing of this method you don't have to worry about property mismatches if that's why you're using `!= null`. Both arguments, source and target, will be of the same type.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your tip ! I must confess, however, that the whole thing is not as simple as it seems. The thing is this. I work my way through a loop that deserializes a JSON string. Due to the circumstances, I can, and must, prevent properties that have multiple subcategories from being checked for nulls in each subcategory (in our case .link and .value). If this is the case, then you should not copy in this case. Since at the beginning, all values are null and that drips in bit by bit, I summarize all values in the copy.